# Installation fails when trying to install VS2010 Beta on Windows 7RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've been trying this off and on for weeks now. Installation fails on the step where it tries to install Microsoft Help 3.0 Beta 1. I've tried to even install Microsoft Help 3.0 Beta 1 manually off the iso and it fails too saying .NET 4.0 has to be installed even though I have installed that correctly.

Anyone have any ideas? This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to the Windows 7 RC from one of the previous beta builds (which isn't supported anyway), you could be running in to some issues there. I was attempting to do exactly that and the install kept failing. I had to re-format and re-install the RC. After re-installing, VS2010 Beta installed without a problem.

Comment: I upgraded from Vista. Hmm I really don't want to have to reinstall everything on my machine to get VS installed. Thanks for answering though.